# android webview redirect over 302

Tags: android, webview

i 'm doing a project using webview in android. i can't visit url: `http://www.baidu.org`. since this url redirect to

```
http://s.click.taobao.com/t_js?tu=http%3A%2F%2Fs.click.taobao.com%2Ft_9%3Fp%3Dmm_13057488_2720475_9729699%26l%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmall.taobao.com%252F%26eventid%3D101766%26ref%3D.
```

in my project, the webview will reload that url hundreds of time. anyone knows how to solve this question?
I get the same problem when i load the url

```
http://www.tmall.com/?ali_trackid=2:mm_13057488_2720475_9729699:1340938813_4z4_2025563791
```

in my webview.

ps:in my pc browser, I input url:`www.baidu.org`, it redirect to

```
http://www.tmall.com/?ali_trackid=2:mm_13057488_2720475_9729699:1340938813_4z4_2025563791.
```

Comment: This question is unclear. Can you please explain in better way?

Comment: i mean, when I try to load httP://www.baidu.org in android webview, webview can't redirect to 
www.tmall.com/?ali_trackid=2:mm_13057488_2720475_9729699:1340938813_4z4_2025563791. like pc browser ie or chrome did. instead webview will refresh reload 
http://s.click.taobao.com/t_js?tu=http%3A%2F%2Fs.click.taobao.com%2Ft_9%3Fp%3Dmm_13057488_2720475_9729699%26l%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmall.taobao.com%252F%26eventid%3D101766%26ref%3D.
I check the http request type, I found that www.baidu.org is 302 type http request. u know how to solve this quetion?

Comment: I did override the meathod shouldOverrideUrlLoading. and it could deal with other redirect request, but not this.

Comment: I didn't find usefull information in android sdk documention.

Comment: can you please post your code what you tried

Comment: I post my code here, plz pay attention that you should change the default input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the below code with your code,

```
webview=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webview.loadUrl("http://www.baidu.org/");      
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

final class MyJavaScriptInterface
    {
        public void ProcessJavaScript(final String scriptname, final String args)
            {             
                mHandler.post(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                            {
                                //TODO...
                            }
                    });
            }
    }
```

This is working for me.... try this

Edit:

In PC Browser:

[image]

In Mobile WebView

[image]

Then what is your problem?

Comment: https://qsikgg.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pHiN2NxzBxKizJcl4riEifp0gNo9BjT6d-Z6OlOCPsBvRXWKOjePrZ-Y4hzgkS5nnMFxRZyY5zwUe1tyP9YJp2g/TestWebBrowserAndroid.rar?download&psid=1

Comment: I just post a code file similar to my question.links
https://qsikgg.blu.livefilestore.com/y1pHiN2NxzBxKizJcl4riEifp0gNo9BjT6d-Z6OlOCPsBvRXWKOjePrZ-Y4hzgkS5nnMFxRZyY5zwUe1tyP9YJp2g/TestWebBrowserAndroid.rar?download&psid=1

Comment: see the edit, i have posted the screenshot, please tell me your problem with this

Comment: I don't have question with loading www.baidu.com, I have question with loading www.baidu.org. Plz pay attention to the difference of the url.

Comment: Yes it is also loading fine, but takes 1 or 2 mins to load in webview. I forgot to tell you onething, that is i have checked with the version 8, but your application with the version 10

Comment: you did't check the debug information. the webview tried many time to visit the redirected url during that 2 mins. load 
http://s.click.taobao.com/t_js?tu=http%3A%2F%2Fs.click.taobao.com%2Ft_9%3Fp%3Dmm_13057488_2720475_9729699%26l%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fmall.taobao.com%252F%26eventid%3D101766%26ref%3D.
 then reload it again and again. if you check the debug infromation ,you will see what I mean

Comment: showWV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); this only enough. try removing shouldOverrideUrlLoading in your code. this working good. only one time loading

Comment: I tried it. That's the very point.

Comment: If it gives you the solution, then accept it as answer